# I want to remove string from a String in dart flutter, How to seperate

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to seperate or removing a string.
Here the example:

```
String sample = "https://xyz-api.portal.com/";
```

i want to get only "xyz-api", this string and want to store a variable,

```
the expected output = 
String result = "xyz-api"
```

How to do that, i am confusing this string conversion, please help

Comment: is your String always a website?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Uri class.

```
String sample = 'https://xyz-api.portal.com/';
String result = Uri.parse(sample).host.split('.')[0];
print(result);
```

Result: **xyz-api**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```dart
String url = "https://xyz-api.portal.com";

// Remove https or http from the start of the url.
url = url.replaceAll('https://', '').replaceAll('http://', '');

// Split the url by the dots. You get a list which should look like this:
// [“xyz-api”, “portal”, “com”]
// You then want to take the first element in the list.
final subdomain = url.split('.')[0];

print(subdomain); // xyz-api
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
String sample = "https://xyz-api.portal.com/";

String ans = value.split('.')[0].split('//')[1];

print(ans);// xyz-api
```